# Is there somewhere I can see a graph of current and future inflation rates of supply?

Tags: cryptocurrency-comparison, emission-curve

Per title,   like right now in bitcoin the inflation is something like   (12.5*6*24*365)/(16,000,000)
i.e. reward times blocks per year / (current outstanding supply)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This spreadsheet compares Monero's emission with that of Bitcoin.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qXi7zUSIh7F6UuSuhOryyFbHEy_LJuym3I3neAga_2s/edit#gid=239466694

Credit to luigi1111 for making this.

Comment: Perfect, just what I wanted